# How to use a python program to edit/save/update variables in a different program?

Tags: raspbian, python, update

Like the title says, I want to dynamically update variable values in a program from another program. For instance:

1. Master pulls variable of 1, from slave program
2. Master updates variable from 1 to 2.
3. Master saves new value to slave
4. Slave runs with new variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Raspberry Pi question. You should study the various techniques for passing data between programs:

- Sockets
- Pipes
- Shared Memory.

I'm sure you can find examples written in Python.

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually trying to achieve this on a rpi. But alright, thanks for the answer.